# Is it safe to remove those filesystem loops

Tags: 16.04, mount, filesystem

I have some filesystem loops on my HDD :

```bash
$ time for dir in $(df -T | awk "/ext[234]|btrfs/"'{print$NF}' | egrep -vw "/home|/tmp")
do
    sudo /usr/bin/find $dir -xdev -follow -printf ""
done

/usr/bin/find: File system loop detected; ‘/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-mode’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/lib/recovery-mode’.
/usr/bin/find: File system loop detected; ‘/usr/bin/X11’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/usr/bin’.
/usr/bin/find: File system loop detected; ‘/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/X11’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin’.

real    0m4.162s
user    0m0.808s
sys     0m3.260s
```

Is it safe to remove those filesystem loops ?